# php empty array if statement

Tags: php, arrays

Hi guys my if statement is not working. I want to basically do nothing is the array is empty or do something if it has values. All that happens is "no extras selected" is displayed even if i select extras

```
if (empty($extras)) { 
    $message .="<br /> No extras selected <br />";
    } else { 
    foreach($_POST['extras'] as $extra)
    {
      $message .="<br />Extras: ".$extra."<br />";

    } 
    }
```

Comment: yes it is an array of checkboxes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming this is a typo, as according to your code `$extras` is never set.

You should be using

```
if (empty($_POST['extras'])) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly `$extras` variable is empty, but you're iterating through `$_POST['extras']` which is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but you can try an `if(!isset($extras[0]))`

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
if ( empty($_POST['extras']) ) { ... }
```

?

Have you declared `$extras` variable before ?

Comment: $extras is an array of checkboxes which are stored in $_POST

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!empty($array)){
//do something
}else{
//donothing

}
```

Please try this.,....

Answer (score 0):

You can try also with the `is_array()` function. Documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you've assigned an empty array to the `$extras` variable in your code (for example `$extras = array()`, then you're essentially checking the assignment of `$extras`, rather than the length of the array assigned thereto.

This should work for you:

```
if(count($extras) == 0) {  
    // Your code here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should be this:

```
if (array_key_exists('extras', $_POST) and // check that the element exists in the $_POST array
    !empty($_POST['extras'])) { // check that it is not empty
     foreach ($_POST['extras'] as $extra) {
        $message .="<br />Extras: " . $extra . "<br />";
     }
} else {
    $message .="<br /> No extras selected <br />";
}
```

Currently the logic in your code is backwards.